# Need an array formula to calculate average across a column, excluding zeroes

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have this dataset in an Excel table:
[image]
I want to calculate the average number of times a product was bought across all customers, where the customer has bought it at least once and I want to store the result in another column, in column D.

So for example... 2 Customers have bought "Cheddar Mature", one of them bought it 3 times and one of them bought it 5 times (highlighted above). Hence the value I want to calculate is (3+5)/2 = 4, and I want that value to be stored in cells D3, D4, D5, D6 & D7.

I know that I need an array formula to figure this out but I can't get my array formula correct. Here's what I have got so far:

`{=AVERAGE(IF([Product]=[@Product],[Number Of Times Bought],0))}`

Here is the result that gives me....not what I want:

[image]

As you can see the answer in those cells is 0.615384615 which (I've worked out) has been derived by dividing by the total number of rows in the table i.e. (3 + 5) / 13 = 0.615384615.

So, I need my array formula to only divide by the number of rows which have a non-zero value for sales of "Cheddar Mature". Can anyone figure that out?

To help, I have made the workbook available on my OneDrive for anyone that wants to try and solve this: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjcmU60daA9VqqgSJkQ_ewOGPqkAMA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=AVERAGEIFS([Number Of Times Bought],[Product],[@Product],[Number Of Times Bought],">0")
```

normally entered.

Comment: NICE. Thank you Ron. I have updated accordingly https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjcmU60daA9VqqgSJkQ_ewOGPqkAMA